# ForStatement - Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable in csv file creation

Tags: java, csv

here i am creating a comma separated value format “CSV” file from a set of students data and save it in my home directory. Firstly, it writes the CSV file header, and then it writes the students data using FileWriter class and i am getting this error here

```
public class CsvFileWriter {
    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
        private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
        private static final String FILE_HEADER = "sno,sname,course,fee";
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List <Student> stuList = new ArrayList <Student>();
                stuList.add(new Student(567, "Jhon", "cs",323));
                stuList.add(new Student(45, "Ave", "ce",6452));
                stuList.add(new Student(57, "Tim", "me",4552));
                stuList.add(new Student(167, "Tao", "ee",1234));
                stuList.add(new Student(7, "Ken", "ae",456));
                FileWriter fileWriter = null;
                String fileName;
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
                        fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());
                        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
                        Object student;
                        for (Student student : student ) {

                                            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(student.getSno()));

                                            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);

                                            fileWriter.append(student.getSname());

                                            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);

                                            fileWriter.append(student.getCourse());

                                            fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER);
                                            fileWriter.append(String.valueOf(student.getFee()));

                                            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);

                                        }
                        System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully !!!");






    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error and what is your question?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight OP named the error in the title. OP should, however, give a more accurate description (or preferably printout from console)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Student student : student )
```

Should be

```
for (Student student : stuList ) {
```

Edit: you also have a problem with variables sharing the same name. `Object student;` and `Student student` in for loop

Comment: should i have to remove Object student; line

Comment: I don't see a use for `Object student` since you appear to be invoking a method in the `Student` class in the loop. (`student.getSno()`) So yes, it appears you can delete the `Object student;` line